# When using Quickbooks Online API Collections for Postman I'm getting an Authentication Error

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, postman, quickbooks-online

I've gone through the steps shown here https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000300_your_first_request/first_request_with_postman#/Configuring_the_Postman_Authorization_header-1500 to use Quickbook's API Collection for Postman.

In Postman, I was successfully able to get a new access token. I also updated the **{{baseurl}}** to be **"sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com"**, and updated the **{{companyid}}** (aka the "RealmId") to be the appropriate value as shown in the "Manage Sandboxes" page of the developer site (i.e. https://developer.intuit.com/v2/ui#/sandbox).

BUT when I click "send" on the "Customer-ReadById" query (or any other query in the collection), I get the following Authentication error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2017-08-16T11:52:00.611-07:00">
    <Fault type="AuthenticationFault">
        <Error code="100">
            <Message>General Authentication Error</Message>
            <Detail>AuthenticationErrorGeneral: SRV-110-Authentication Failure , statusCode: 401</Detail>
        </Error>
    </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

My next step was to verify that I can query my sandbox using the OAuth 2.0 Playground tool on the developers site, which I can indeed do.

My questions then are: why am I getting this authentication error in Postman? Am I missing a step? Or has something changed in the Quickbooks Online API that has not yet been documented?

**EDIT:** I've managed to resolve my own issue after a decent amount of trial and error, and with a hint based on a response in the Quickbooks Online help area.

For those who may find this useful, my solution was to request a new access token (click "Get New Access Token" in Postman) and updated the "Scope" section to include "openid" such that the space delimited list read:
**com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting openid profile email phone address**

Using this new token with the updated scope allowed me to get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I resolved it differently.  My issue was that in the requested token, the default to "Add token to" is URL, but it seems that the API requires the token to be in an Authorization header.  Changing this to "Header" does just that.

For the "Customer-ReadById" endpoint, the only scope that should be necessary is com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting.  My guess is you changed it to Header in your trial and error.